A simple inequality for the magnitude of a complex number.
Let $w:=1-(1-z)\cdot h\in \mathbb{C}$, where $h\in [0,1]$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $ |z|<\alpha<1$. Prove or disprove:
$$ |w|\leqslant 1-(1-\alpha)\cdot h$$
My attempt: I solve this by brute force: write $z=x+iy$, and compute directly:
$$ \begin{aligned}
|w|^2&= (1-h+xh)^2+(yh)^2\\
&=(x^2+y^2)h^2+(1-h)(1-h+2xh)\\
&\leqslant \alpha^2h^2+(1-h)(1-h+2\alpha h)\\
&=(1-(1-\alpha) h)^2
\end{aligned}$$
However, it seems that we can solve this using other inequalities, for example, maybe triangle inequalities? But I failed.
Are there any other cleverer ways to solve this? Thanks!

By triangle inequality for complex numbers
$$\left|w \right|=\left|1-h+hz\right| \le 1-h + \left|hz\right| \le 1-h+h\alpha=1-(1-\alpha)\cdot h$$

Glad to see you again! Thank you!  I never think about using it in this way :-)

@Zoudelong I think this is the usual way triangle inequality is used, at least in the analysis textbooks I read =)). I don't remember exactly which ones though.

I agree. I just didn't realize that we can first expand it and use it for $1-h$ and $hz$. My proof of brute force also gives a hint how to use it.
